# Passing Datetime in SQLCommand

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, datetime-format, sqlcommand

I have to insert a row in my SQL Server via VS 2008 and my codes goes as follows;

```
conn = New SqlConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0}; Integrated Security=True; Database={1};", Datasource, Database)

 sqlcmd = conn.CreateCommand()
            sqlcmd.CommandText = String.Format("Insert into WWF_Test (Name, Address, Quantity, CreditCardNo, LogMsg, Date_Time) values ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5})", _
                                               CustomerName, CustomerAdd, Quantity, CreditCardNum, Now, message)

            Using conn
                conn.Open()
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
            End Using
```

On run, I'm having an exception with the Date_Time column (of type datetime in SQL Server), whereby the time part is throwing an error. Like;

```
{"Incorrect syntax near '10'."} --> where Now = 11/11/2013 10:50:24
```

Am I missing a conversion? Considering that I need a datetime, I think it should have accepted it. Any help plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `string.Format` to put parameters into your SQL to start with.

Instead, use parameterized SQL, and specify the values for those parameters. This will avoid [SQL Injection Attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) as well as helping avoid unnecessary and problematic string conversions.

So you want something like:

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "Insert into WWF_Test (Name, Address, Quantity, CreditCardNo, LogMsg, Date_Time) values (@Name, @Address, @Quantity, @CreditCardNo, @LogMsg, @Date_Time)"

sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbTypes.NVarChar).Value = CustomerName
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbTypes.NVarChar).Value = CustomerAdd
etc
```

... using `SqlDbTypes.DateTime` where appropriate. This way, you don't need to worry about how the `DateTime` value would be represented in SQL, because it isn't *in* SQL. It's *possible* that the driver will convert it into text in order to pass it along, but even if it does that means it's the *driver's* responsibility to get it right. It's more likely that it'll use a binary representation anyway.